# Flash "CurveTo" and "LineTo" in Shapes

Tags: c++, flash, direct2d

I'm working in trying to display some old SWF files with Direct2D.

I found [swfmill](https://www.swfmill.org/) which, for a simple SWF (found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15IvoAM98aftRleoj6Ij0v6psiBKTmhcy/view?usp=sharing)) that displays a "W"

[image]

produces XML code, part of which is this one:

```
          <ShapeSetup x="-214" y="470" fillStyle1="1"/>
          <LineTo x="-20" y="0"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-35" y1="-74" x2="-45" y2="-109"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-46" y1="-109" x2="-109" y2="-244"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-110" y1="-244" x2="-32" y2="-50"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-33" y1="-50" x2="-27" y2="-18"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-27" y1="-19" x2="-21" y2="-3"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-21" y1="-1" x2="0" y2="-9"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="-10" x2="53" y2="0"/>
          <LineTo x="304" y="0"/>
          <CurveTo x1="43" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="10" x2="-24" y2="0"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-100" y1="6" x2="0" y2="70"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="16" x2="8" y2="27"/>
          <CurveTo x1="8" y1="27" x2="100" y2="229"/>
          <CurveTo x1="99" y1="229" x2="59" y2="120"/>
          <CurveTo x1="22" y1="-56" x2="73" y2="-216"/>
          <CurveTo x1="72" y1="-215" x2="14" y2="-56"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-53" y1="-131" x2="-24" y2="-21"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-24" y1="-22" x2="-41" y2="-7"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-29" y1="-1" x2="0" y2="-9"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="-10" x2="52" y2="0"/>
          <LineTo x="305" y="0"/>
          <CurveTo x1="28" y1="0" x2="7" y2="2"/>
          <CurveTo x1="8" y1="2" x2="0" y2="6"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="6" x2="-40" y2="4"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-84" y1="13" x2="0" y2="68"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="106" x2="234" y2="531"/>
          <CurveTo x1="46" y1="-116" x2="44" y2="-123"/>
          <LineTo x="80" y="-220"/>
          <CurveTo x1="35" y1="-97" x2="4" y2="-25"/>
          <CurveTo x1="5" y1="-25" x2="0" y2="-21"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="-89" x2="-85" y2="-2"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-19" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-10"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="-6" x2="6" y2="-2"/>
          <CurveTo x1="6" y1="-2" x2="28" y2="0"/>
          <LineTo x="165" y="0"/>
          <CurveTo x1="74" y1="0" x2="10" y2="2"/>
          <CurveTo x1="11" y1="1" x2="0" y2="9"/>
          <CurveTo x1="0" y1="8" x2="-16" y2="0"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-74" y1="6" x2="-43" y2="83"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-42" y1="83" x2="-154" y2="449"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-81" y1="235" x2="-27" y2="64"/>
          <LineTo x="-21" y="0"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-58" y1="-160" x2="-55" y2="-132"/>
          <CurveTo x1="-54" y1="-132" x2="-100" y2="-257"/>
          <LineTo x="-229" y="681"/>
          <ShapeSetup/>
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this shape.

**What I've tried:**
I tried with a [ID2D1PathGeometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1pathgeometry) and `BeginFigure` (for the ShapeSetup),

- `AddLine` (for each **LineTo**),
- `AddQuadraticBezier` (for each **CurveTo**) but the result is this:

[image]

I realized that I must combine some geometries but I'm not sure how. A spec I found [here](https://open-flash.github.io/mirrors/swf-spec-19.pdf) says:

> **FillStyle0** and **FillStyle1** 
>  The Adobe Flash authoring tool supports two fill styles per edge, one for each side of the edge: `FillStyle0` and
> `FillStyle1`. 
> For shapes that don’t self-intersect or overlap,
> **FillStyle0** should be used. 
> For overlapping shapes the situation is more complex. For example, if a shape consists of two overlapping squares, and only **FillStyle0** is defined, 
> Flash Player renders a ‘hole’ where the paths overlap. This area can be filled using **FillStyle1**. In this situation, the rule is that for any directed vector, **FillStyle0** is the color to the left
> of the vector, and **FillStyle1** is the color to
> the right of the vector

Is there anyone that understands how that shape should be drawn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, coordinates are all relative. So you need to calculate positions incrementally.

For example,

```
<ShapeSetup x="-214" y="470" fillStyle1="1"/>
<LineTo x="-20" y="0"/>
<CurveTo x1="-35" y1="-74" x2="-45" y2="-109"/>
:
```

are to be translated to

```
pSink->BeginFigure(D2D1::Point2F(-214, 470), D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);

pSink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(-234, 470)); // -214, 470 + (-20, 0)

D2D1_QUADRATIC_BEZIER_SEGMENT seg = {
    D2D1::Point2F(-269, 396), // -234, 470 + (-35,-74)
    D2D1::Point2F(-314, 287)  // -269, 396 + (-45,-109)
};
pSink->AddQuadraticBezier(&seg);
:
```

#### Appendix

Testing it in XAML or SVG path-data form,

```
M -214,470 
l -20, 0 
q -35,-74 -80,-183 
q -46,-109 -155,-353 
q -110,-244 -142,-294 
q -33,-50 -60,-68 
q -27,-19 -48,-22 
q -21,-1 -21,-10 
q 0,-10 53,-10 
l 304, 0 
q 43,0 43,10 
q 0,10 -24,10 
q -100,6 -100,76 
q 0,16 8,43 
q 8,27 108,256 
q 99,229 158,349 
q 22,-56 95,-272 
q 72,-215 86,-271 
q -53,-131 -77,-152 
q -24,-22 -65,-29 
q -29,-1 -29,-10 
q 0,-10 52,-10 
l 305, 0 
q 28,0 35,2 
q 8,2 8,8 
q 0,6 -40,10 
q -84,13 -84,81 
q 0,106 234,637 
q 46,-116 90,-239 
l 80, -220 
q 35,-97 39,-122 
q 5,-25 5,-46 
q 0,-89 -85,-91 
q -19,0 -19,-10 
q 0,-6 6,-8 
q 6,-2 34,-2 
l 165, 0 
q 74,0 84,2 
q 11,1 11,10 
q 0,8 -16,8 
q -74,6 -117,89 
q -42,83 -196,532 
q -81,235 -108,299 
l -21, 0 
q -58,-160 -113,-292 
q -54,-132 -154,-389 
l -229, 681 
Z
```

surely got W.

[image: Conversion from Flash path to XAML/SVG path]